# UTF-8 doesn'y encoding correctly

Tags: laravel, dom, encoding, character-encoding

I have a code to thanks to whom use wysciwyg editor (and uploading photo correctly form editor). The part of this  code looks like this

```
  $detail=$request->input('description');
  $dom = new \DomDocument();
  $dom->loadHtml($detail, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
  $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Generally this code works but instead of polish characters I have (sor example)

```
<p>sad s&nbsp; ads asd sa d as&Auml;&#133;&Aring;&#155;&Auml;&#135;&Atilde;&sup3;&Aring;&#130;&Aring;&frac14; sdas das das dsa d</p>
```

I tryed use

```
{!! html_entity_decode($article->description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') !!}
```

but it doesn;t work.

Comment: provide the output, it will help understand the issue.

Comment: ok. My input is: `ąśćółż Hello World ąśźćół` my output is `<p>&Auml;&#133;&Aring;&#155;&Auml;&#135;&Atilde;&sup3;&Aring;&#130;&Aring;&frac14; Hello World &Auml;&#133;&Aring;&#155;&Aring;&ordm;&Auml;&#135;&Atilde;&sup3;&Aring;&#130;</p>
`

Comment: try setting `encoding` in html using `<meta charset="UTF-8">` then use `html_entity_decode()` in php

Comment: Put that comment into the question. "Strange characters" isn't a good enough question to be answerable, it needs details.

Comment: I'm tryed `{!! html_entity_decode($article->description, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') !!}` but it nothing change. Of course I'm using `<meta charset="UTF-8">` too. But I want to store polish character into db, not decode into view.

Comment: can you please provide the view and controller code? mark the code where you got that error. because i didn't get you now.

Answer (score 0):

It's encoding issue. you have to encode/decode the html entities accordingly. also you need a meta tag with charset=utf8 in your html. hop it help.

Answer (score -1):

Is't an issue regarding `utf-8` encoding. use php function `html_entity_decode()` before using it.